# applying aspect defined in one project, to methods in other projects of solution

Tags: postsharp

I have created an aspect class inherited from OnMethodBoundaryAspect class of Postsharp. When I use the aspect in the same project where I have defined it, it works fine. But when I use the aspect in another project in my solution, the aspect would not be applied. In this case the PostSharp Explorer says "there is no aspect in the current solution, ..."
How can I solve this problem and use my aspect defined in project A to methods or classes in project B in my solution?
Thanks

Comment: The problem was that PostSharp was not enabled for the other projects in the solution. I used properties->postsharp->"add postsharp to this project" to enable. Now it works fine.

Comment: Properties of what???